# Exporting PNG-Sequences for iOS right!

Tags: ios, flash, file, png

I made an animation for an iOS-loading-screen. The devs tell me now, that the files are way to big (100 frames/pngs with 22.5mb for the whole bunch) and I tried to reduce it by rastering the PNGs by export (helped a bit) and then I shortened the video by 50frames and I'm on 10mb now. This is still huge. I made the animation in Flash. Is this the problem? Each PNG is 235kb of size. I need your help :-)

Comment: Use mp4 video instead PNG frames.

Comment: Is this also usable as a loading-screen?

Comment: iOS loads a static Default.png while your application is loading. Until it finishes loading you can't execute code, but after that you can do anything. Video provides way smaller sizes than 8 bit PNGs and because it's video, the small loss in quality goes unnoticed.

Comment: Hello Jano, thanks for your reply. It's a "first-startup"-screen that loads before the "login here"-screen. You think its ok for the devs to use it instead of a PNG-sequence? Thanks for your support!

Comment: It's a small effort to code, `[[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL] play]`, set the dimensions of the frame, disable controls, and subscribe to `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` to release the player. It shouldn't take long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first try to reduce the size of your png using pngcrush or Photohop export for web. The other idea is to use an mpeg video, create a png with just the first frame, open the video when the application run and you should be able to switch from the static png to the first frame of the video without glitches. In this way the user don't understand that you switched from image to video and see the video playing.

Hope this helps